# How to get keyPoint ID

Tags: c++, opencv, detect

I'm doing a matching programm in opencv and C++ and I want to classifier my keyPoints-detected depending of the region of image they are.

i.e: If I detect a keypoint in the top of the image I want to classifier this in region 1... An depending where I found the keypoints I want to classifier them.

Finally I'm going to do a new classifier vector like this:

> vector  classifier_vector;

and one of the two parameters that I need is the id of every detected points.

Does someone know how I can to get the keypoints id?

I'm not sure about the next but I saw that the parameter I need to get is

> int _class_id

Am I right?

Thanks everybody. ;)

Comment: I'm sorry because my english isn't very well, I hope that you understant me

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV have a KeyPoint class which have the following parameters:

**pt** (x,y) -> the position of the KeyPoints,
**size** - size of the keypoint,
**angle** - orientation of the keypoint,
**response** - strength of the keypoint,
**octave** - number of octave layer the keypoint is detected,
**class_id** - the number of object the keypoint belongs to.

So basically what you need is the **class_id**.

```
keyPoint kpt;
kpt.class_id;
```